# In a Latex Table, how can I automatically resize cell heights to account for superscripts?

Tags: tables, spacing

I have the following table created using the `H` command from the `float` package. The main problem below is that the exponents are too close to the top of the cell. Is there a way to increase the cell-height automatically? Thank you for any suggestions.

```
\usepackage(float)
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
                    & Compute on $X^A$ & Compute on $(X^A, X^B)$  \\
    \hline 
    Estimate on $X^A$ & Correct & Incorrect \\
    Estimate on $(X^A, X^B)$ & Correct & Incorrect \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

alternatively, with `makecell` package :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & Compute on $X^A$  & Compute on $(X^A, X^B)$ \\
\hline
Estimate on $X^A$
    & Correct           & Incorrect \\
Estimate on $(X^A, X^B)$
    & Correct           & Incorrect \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The `cellspace` package is here for that! You can define *minimal* vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`, as this package already defines an `S` column type). Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|Sc|}
\hline
                & Compute on $X^A$ & Compute on $(X^A, X^B)$ \\
\hline
Estimate on $X^A$ & Correct & Incorrect \\
Estimate on $(X^A, X^B)$ & Correct & Incorrect \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) and the commands `\arraystretch` and `\extrarowheight`, which give perfect result here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float, array}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]

        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                        & Compute on $X^A$ & Compute on $(X^A, X^B)$  \\
                \hline 
                Estimate on $X^A$ & Correct & Incorrect \\
                Estimate on $(X^A, X^B)$ & Correct & Incorrect \\
                \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]